# Makefile that handles subdirectories and puts object files in a object folder tree

Tags: c, makefile, subdirectory

I have a question about Makefiles with subdirectories:

I have a program with the structure

```
---src
    |
    |-> main.c
    |-> morestuff.c
    |-> [...]
    |-> builtins -> builtin.c
                 -> builtin2.c
---obj
---inc
```

Now what I want to do is: I want to run `make` such that I create object files in my object directory (order structure not necessarily needed) and that I (obviously) create an executable.
I am able to do that without the subdirectories, but my pattern rules break, once I try to include the subdirectories...

My current approach (without subdirectories) looks something like this:

```
NAME = minishell
SRC_DIR = src/
OBJ_DIR = obj/
INC_DIR = inc/
LIBFT_DIR = libft/
LIBFT_EXEC = libft.a
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -Wextra -g

# place all source files here
SRC =     $(SRC_DIR)main.c \
          $(SRC_DIR)builtin1.c \
          $(SRC_DIR)builtin2.c \
          [...]

# takes all named source files and converts them to .o files in the /obj directory
OBJ = $(SRC:$(SRC_DIR)%.c=$(OBJ_DIR)%.o)

# prevents rules from being considered as files
.PHONY: all clean fclean re

all: $(NAME)

# creates subdirectory /obj
$(OBJ_DIR):
    @mkdir $@
    @echo "Creating object directory..."

# makes sure to make a /obj dir before compiling .o files
$(OBJ): | $(OBJ_DIR)

$(OBJ): $(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

# compiles all object files and builds executable file 'minishell' -> ADJUST READLINE FOR LINUX!
$(NAME): $(OBJ)
    @echo "Compiling libft..."
    $(MAKE) -C libft
    @echo "Compiling $(NAME)..."
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ $(LIBFT_DIR)$(LIBFT_EXEC) -L $(HOME)/goinfre/.brew/opt/readline/lib/ -lreadline -o $@
    @echo "SUCCESSFULLY CREATED MINISHELL!"
```

So how can I scale that up to handle subdirectories?
I know I could make Makefiles in subdirectories, but this is not worth the effort since there aren't a lot of files in there...

Comment: Please don't spam unrelated tags. How is this related to the C++ programming language? Or CMake?

Comment: It's not related to cmake either.

Comment: When asking future questions, note that _but my pattern rules break_ is not a useful problem description.  Please show an example (cut and paste, not screenshot and not paraphrased: exact output) of the recipe commands that make invoked (what it printed out) and the errors that were generated.  Then it will almost certainly be obvious what the problem is without even having to read a long makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of just creating the object directory before compiling, you should create the object file directory tree prior to compiling each file:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)%.o: $(SRC_DIR)%.c
    @mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

`$(dir $@)` is a GNU make extension. You can use `` @mkdir -p `dirname $@` ``  for portability to other `make` flavors.

Comment: just out of curiosity: is it also possible to put all the object files in a object directory without subdirectories?

Comment: @raweber: there is probably a non trivial way to do this, but it requires more dependency rules and you must make sure there are no collisions in filenames. Using the same hierarchy for source and object files is preferred and allows for a simpler makefile.

Comment: If you really wanted to do it, you should look up `vpath` / `VPATH` and it will help you.  But I agree, it's not a good idea.

Comment: @raweber: I agree with MadScientist: `vpath` could help you store all object files in a single directory, but it is **not a good idea**. Keep the Makefile simple and explicit. There is no downside in creating a hierarchy for the object files and you can remove the whole object file tree with `rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)` as long as `OBJ_DIR` is not `.`. It would also make sense to omit the trailing `/` from the definition of `OBJ_DIR` and add it explicitly in the rules.